# Why does the following parsing solution work?

Tags: ruby, regex

I need simple parsing with embedded single and double quotes. For the following input:

```
" hello    'there   ok \"hohh\"   '   ciao    \"eeee  \"   \"  yessss 'aaa'  \"   %%55+ "
```

I need the following output:

```
["hello", "there   ok \"hohh\"   ", "ciao", "eeee  ", "  yessss 'aaa'  ", "%%55+"]
```

Why does the following Ruby code that I came up with work? I do not understand the regex part. I know basic regex but I assume that the embedded quotes should not work but they still do, either with single ones having doubles and vice versa.

```
text.scan(/\"(.*?)\"|'(.*?)'|([^\s]+)/).flatten.select{|x|x}
```

Comment: What do you mean by "works"? **Why** is that result correct? I understand why your code obtains this result, but I don't understand what logic you actually intended to apply.

Comment: For example, maybe that result is wrong, and *this* is actually the "correct"?? `["hello", "there   ok \"hohh\"   ", "   ciao    \"eeee  \"   \"  yessss ", "aaa", "%%55+"]` If not, then *why not*?

Comment: Provide some more context. What is the real problem you're solving? What are you actually trying to achieve? For instance, maybe you're actually trying to parse a CSV file? (In which case, don't use regex; there are libraries for this.) The question sounds like a potential [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) to me.

Comment: No CSV here. As I wrote, I need to parse a string (this is command line for an interpreter that is part of my program). So I need my parser to be able to interpret single quoted text with embedded double quotes and double quoted text with embedded single quotes and also text without quotes. Therefore the intended output that I provided above is correct for me.

Comment: You can replace `select{|x|x}` with the idiomatic Ruby [`Array#compact`](https://apidock.com/ruby/v1_9_3_392/Array/compact).

Comment: @moveson that's neat, thx

Comment: @log69 *"this is command line for an interpreter that is part of my program"* -- Ahh, right then! So have you considered using ruby's built-in functionality such as [`ARGV`](http://ruby-doc.org/core/ARGF.html#method-i-argv)? This would be much cleaner, more concise and reliable than a custom regex solution.

Comment: @TomLord It's not that simple, it is not a command line program in Ruby, for that I would use ARGV or the OptionParser class. What I need is parsing a string as I wrote above. Parameters in this string can stand between single and double quotes with nested quotes. I find the example above working but cannot understand the regex part and would like to validate its correctness. Thx.

Comment: @log69 Right... But there's a library for emulating that behaviour. No need to reinvent the wheel with a confusing regex! I'll post an answer below now, but for future reference: *always* describe the full context of the problem, to prevent XY Questions like this. You're asking for answers to is a misguided implementation, not the original problem in hand.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No need to solve this with a custom regex; [the ruby standard library contains a module for this: **`Shellwords`**](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib/libdoc/shellwords/rdoc/Shellwords.html).

> #### Manipulates strings like the UNIX Bourne shell
>
> This module manipulates strings according to the word parsing rules of the UNIX Bourne shell.

Usage:

```
require 'shellwords'

str = " hello    'there   ok \"hohh\"   '   ciao    \"eeee  \"   \"  yessss 'aaa'  \"   %%55+ "

Shellwords.split(str)
  #=> ["hello", "there   ok \"hohh\"   ", "ciao", "eeee  ", "  yessss 'aaa'  ", "%%55+"]
# Or equivalently:
str.shellsplit
  #=> ["hello", "there   ok \"hohh\"   ", "ciao", "eeee  ", "  yessss 'aaa'  ", "%%55+"]
```

---

The above is the "right" answer. Use that. What follows is additional information to explain *why* to use this, and why your answer "sort-of" works.

Parsing these strings accurately is tricky! Your regex attempt works for *most* inputs, but does not properly handle various edge cases. For example, consider:

```
str = "foo\\ bar"

str.shellsplit
  #=> ["foo bar"] (correct!)

str.scan(/\"(.*?)\"|'(.*?)'|([^\s]+)/).flatten.select{|x|x}
  #=> ["foo\\", "bar"] (wrong!)
```

The [method's implementation](https://github.com/rubysl/rubysl-shellwords/blob/d98beb721a3d2ddc8be02e24ee4307b51bf0508e/lib/rubysl/shellwords/shellwords.rb#L32-L45) does still use a (more complex!) regex under the hood, but also handles edge cases such as invalid inputs - which yours does not.

> ```
> line.scan(/\G\s*(?>([^\s\\\'\"]+)|'([^\']*)'|"((?:[^\"\\]|\\.)*)"|(\\.?)|(\S))(\s|\z)?/m)
> ```

So without digging *too* deeply into the flaws of your approach (but suffice to say, it doesn't always work!), why does it **mostly** work? Well, your regex:

> ```
> /\"(.*?)\"|'(.*?)'|([^\s]+)/
> ```

...is saying:

- If `"` is found, match *as **little** as possible* (`.*?`) up until the closing `"`.
- Same as above, for single quotes (`'`).
- If neither a single nor double quote is found, scan ahead to the first non-whitespace characters (`[^\s]+` -- which could also, equivalently, have been written as `\S+`).

The `.flatten` is necessary because you're using *capture groups* (`(...)`). This could have been avoided if you'd used non-capture groups instead (`(?:...)`).

The `.select{|x|x}`, or (effectively) equivalently `.compact` was also necessary because of these capture groups - since in each match, 2 of the 3 groups were not part of the result.

Comment: ShellWords seems cool. Thanks for your thorough answer, I greatly appreciate it.